# Using an active rsession when running a script via Rscript

Tags: r

I know that I can use `Rscript` to run a R script in the command line. Currently, I'm passing different parameters to my script, load a few packages and run a few functions. Then, I change the parameters — via a bash script — and run the same script with different parameters . This is all fine, however, I was wondering if there is a way that I can instantiate one `rsession` and grab it instead of going through the process of loading all my packages, etc. every time that `Rscript` executes my script.

Answer (score 0):

**library([ipc](https://github.com/fellstat/ipc))** might be of interest.

It allows to set up continuous communication between parent and child R processes by creating so called queues in the parent process.

Unfortunately you haven't specified your usecase with any code, so please see the [vignette](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/fellstat/ipc/blob/master/inst/doc/shinymp.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

One solution may be to use the [`session`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/session/index.html) package. With it, you can perform the analogous `load.session()` and `save.session()` actions to the start and exit of the standard `R` launch and exit. The result is not 100 % equivalent, since the `q()` function is `.Internal`.